# What is the maximum number of variables that can be read from a CSV file by an iMacros script?

Tags: imacros

I'm creating an input template to provide data for several iMacros scripts.  As of now there are 56 columns and I would like to almost double that, but would like to know if there is an upper limit to the number of !COLx variables that can be read and processed by a script.

I have searched in the IPswitch product documentation as well as stackoverflow and general web searches and haven't found it.
Any help or even the maximum you have tried would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess there's no upper limit as to that. For love of the game tested a macro which reads a csv-file having 5000 columns and didn't reveal any issues, but in such cases I would prefer using a database by means of web interface. Certainly, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I'll support @Shugar answer. Never noticed that there would be an issue with columns. However it may occur that your system reaches its capacity (just a thought).

Comment: Thank you both.  It's good to have an answer that Shugar's test went way above my possible needs!